# ios issue with 3d animations

Tags: ios, core-animation, transform, layer

I'm trying to 3D animate an UIImageView on X axis so it will do a 180 degrees rotation. At 90 degres I want to change the image. (that is why i "broke" the animation in 2).

Animation works well, but the problem is that the second image is drawn upside down. Any ideas what should i do for the image to be drawn normal?

Here is my code

```
    i++;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{

    self.imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI/2 , 1, 0,0);

} completion:^(BOOL finished){

    UIImage *bottomI = (UIImage *)[bottom objectAtIndex:i];
    self.second.image =bottomI;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{

          imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI , 1, 0,0);

    } completion:^(BOOL finised){   

    }];

}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done (using grouped CABasicAnimation objects instead of view animations, but the same trick should work) is to rotate the view/layer the first 90 degrees, then rotate it 180 degrees without animation before starting the second half of the animation. That way, the second half of the animation actually causes the front face of the view/layer to rotate into view as if it was the back face, but not backwards.

The view/layer is edge-on to the viewer while you are switching it's image and rotating it 180 degrees, so the user can't see those changes. When it rotates the remaining 90 degrees, the new image is in place and it appears to be revealing the back side of the view/layer.

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are 3d rotating a view, it is similar to rotating an object in real life. So, once the rotation is more than 90 degrees, it would invert the object. Which is why your second image is inverted. The simplest thing to do is to set the affine transform of the image to rotate it by 180 degrees before adding it in.

EDIT: My silliness....

What I intended was [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
bottomI.orientation = UIImageOrientationDown
```

Comment: you can't do CGAffineTransformMakeRotation on a UIImage